# Extract datetime strings with datefinder

Tags: python, regex, datefinder

```
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(str(laslogsystime[0])))
if len(matches) > 0:
    date = matches[0]
    # print(date)

logging = re.findall(r'(.*?)', date)[0]
print(logging)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Whta is `laslogsystime[0]`?  Why use `re.findall(r'(.*?)', date)`? What are you  trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you make sure `date` is either `str` or `bytes` ? I think `date` looks like `list` or something

Comment: laslogsystime[0] is a list containing the date

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to extract the *strings* that [`datefinder`](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder) identifies as datetime strings.

You need no `re.findall`, you need to tell `find_dates` to return tuples containing both datetime and source strings by passing `source=True` argument:

```
import datefinder
from datetime import datetime

laslogsystime = "August 1990 some text May 21 2015"
matches = [src for time, src in datefinder.find_dates(laslogsystime, source=True)]
print(matches) # => ['August 1990', 'May 21 2015']
```